# why do we need to call `detach_` in `zero_grad`?

Tags: pytorch

I am reading the source code of `optimizer.zero_grad()`

http://pytorch.org/docs/master/_modules/torch/optim/optimizer.html#Optimizer.zero_grad

```python
def zero_grad(self):
    """Clears the gradients of all optimized :class:`Variable` s."""
    for group in self.param_groups:
        for p in group['params']:
            if p.grad is not None:
                p.grad.detach_()
                p.grad.zero_()
```

I wonder why `detach_()` is necessary? What does it even mean to `detach` a gradient variable instead of a normal variable?

Why isn't `zero_()` enough?

Answer (score 1):

You do not want previous gradient updates to affect future gradient updates so you are detaching the previous gradients from the graph.

Comment: why isn't `zero_()` enough?

Comment: The way the backend implements the gradients is by progressively adding on the gradients to the graph.  So if you run your graph 100 times and only zero the previous gradients you are potentially taking up 100X extra space to hold all of those zeros in the graph.

Comment: why not grad = None instead of grad.detach_() and grad,.zero_() ?

Comment: grad = None will forever change the class and prevent you from using the gradients in future calls to the function or other functions that depend on the grad variable existing. grad.detach_() instead just removes the grad from affecting previous parts of the graph.